# QT и Android

Tags: android, java, qt, c++

Здравствуйте, недавно увлекся программированием под андроид, и у меня возник вопрос, что лучше (в смысле производительности).

1. Писать на Java (используя SDK и стандартные либы андроида).
2. Писать на C++(QT) и компилировать для андроида.

Кто сталкивался с этим ответьте, что лучше, желательно аргументируйте.

Comment: Не слышал чтобы qt поддерживался андроидом. Хотя там можно писать на NDK но опять же не уверен можно ли написать готовое приложение исключительно на NDK - скорее там можно только писать отдельные либы и потом их интегрировать с Java.

Comment: Услышьте: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/mobiledev/125845/

Было бы что сравнивать, например 2gis, думаю что связка Java + JNI будет работать быстрее чем Qt.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, возможно ли использовать QT только для отрисовки GUI?Остальная часть приложения - sdk и ndk.

Comment: Как вы себе это представляете?

Comment: Плохо, поэтому и спрашиваю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Время разработчика стоит дорого.
2. 80% кода потребляет 20% ресурсов и наоборот.

Отсюда прямо следует, что оптимизацией надо заниматься тогда, когда без этого уже никак нельзя. Если вас ничего не ограничивает и не вынуждает писать на C/C++ под Android (обычно это старые библиотеки, которые давно написаны и их себе дороже выйдет переписывать на Java), то надо писать на Java. В смысле производительности, имеет значение переписывать на C/C++ только ту часть, которая реально есть ресурс.

P.S. Для Qt под Android есть порт: [Necessitas](http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/home/necessitas/). Но это дополнительная искусственная прослойка, и использование ее практически всегда будет в ущерб результату.

Answer (score 4):

Более-менее общепринятый паттерн разработки под Android состоит в том, чтобы писать под Java, затем **в случае необходимости** критически важные, в плане производительности, участки кода писать под С/С++

Советую придерживать именно такого подхода, иначе разработка продукта будет слишком дорогой.

Answer (score 1):

На андроид можно писать только на jave. И это действительно очень медленно. Для ускорения можно использовать NDK. Он позволяет в jave использовать библиотеки написанные на c++.

Answer (score 0):

Только под Android писать на QT нет никакого смысла.
Есть смысл рассматривать QT только в случае кросс-платформенной разработки, например писать сразу под Android/iOS/WP или использовать уже готовый функционал десктопного QT приложения.

Но и в этом случае нужно тщательно взвешивать все "за" и "против".